# Custom Markdown for PHP handling new lines

Tags: php, regex, markdown

I need custom Markdown library for PHP which converts new lines to `<br/>` without the need to put double space on the end of the line, kinda like here on SO. I've been looking on the web but without success. I know I could just amend standard library but my regex skills are none.

Does anybody know about such library in existence or know how to change default behaviour easily?

EDIT: Dumb me, SO does not work this way, it appears to be standard Markdown behaviour. However such functionality is being used on github.com.

Comment: Mainly to use as formatting layer for notebook so i can easily add headers, lists and so on. But sometimes when i copy say poetry from the web I need to add double space on each line to preserve line breaks which is frustrating. Another example is simple list without need for `+` or `*` signs.

Comment: Probably because it is more intuitive for users

Comment: @Jacco: Problem is this is not. When you enter text on new line, you expect that to be displayed on new line.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, the double space is non-intuitive

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [Text_Wiki](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Wiki), enabling [the newline rule](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Wiki/docs/latest/Text_Wiki/Text_Wiki_Parse_Newline.html). I suspect other wiki parsers have this feature, maybe just not enabled by default.